# Reactjs, jest, enzyme, react-universal-component - How do I test a components structure with dynamic imports?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs, dynamic-import

I'm trying to determine how best to write unit tests when using dynamic imports using React Universal Component 2.0

https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component

TestableComponent is a component I want to test. I want to test that "ChildComp" is returned correctly. In reality there's a lot of logic and transformation involved but as the base case, I just to be able to test that "ChildComp" exists. I'm using Universal Component to do a dynamic import of the "ChildComp"

*TestableComponent.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import universal from 'react-universal-component'

const ChildComp = universal(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'child' */ 'common/ChildComp'), {
  resolve: () => require.resolveWeak('common/ChildComp'),
  chunkName: 'child'
})

class TestableComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.childNodes = []
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.childNodes.push(<ChildComp id='myLink' key='myLink' />)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>{this.childNodes}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default TestableComponent
```

*TestableComponent Unit Test*

```
import React from 'react'
import TestableComponent from '../TestableComponent'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'

const waitFor = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

describe('Testable Component test', () => {
  it('tests transformation', async () => {
    const compMount = mount((<TestableComponent />))
    console.log(compMount.debug())

    /* output: <TestableComponent >
      <div>
        <UniversalComponent id="myLink">
          <DefaultLoading id="myLink">
            <div>
              Loading...
            </div>
          </DefaultLoading>
        </UniversalComponent>
      </div>
    </TestableComponent> */

    const compMountWait = mount((<TestableComponent />))
    await waitFor(1000) // dynamic import
    console.log(compMountWait.debug())

    /* output: <TestableComponent>
       <div>
         <UniversalComponent id="myLink">
           <ChildComp id="myLink" />
         </UniversalComponent>
       </div>
     </TestableComponent> */
  })
})
```

Notice in the first debug() that initially ChildComp isn't shown. Just loading information that importing of the components aren't complete yet.

After the waitFor(1000), you can see that ChildComp is available.

**Question**: Is it proper to use a timeout to let dyanmic imports to complete before structural testing, or is there a programmatic way to determine when dynamic imports are complete?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution using the mock in Jest to be able to override the default behavior of react-universal-component and add the call to the preload function in all components. You just have to use this code every test, so I suggest putting it in the test setup file. This means you don't have to change anything in your code and allows you to test your components without waiting for X seconds.

Mock Solution:

```
jest.mock('react-universal-component', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: (spec, options) => {
        const universal = jest.
            requireActual('react-universal-component').
            default; // Get original default behavior from the library. 

        const UniversalComponent = universal(spec, options); // Call original function.
        UniversalComponent.preload(); // Preload component.

        return UniversalComponent; // Return loaded Universal Component.
    },
}));
```

Your Code Remains the Same:

```
const ChildComp = universal(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'child' */ 
    'common/ChildComp'), {
    resolve: () => require.resolveWeak('common/ChildComp'),
    chunkName: 'child'
})
```